# .html not displaying after .getJSON

Tags: javascript

I am trying to follow a .getJSON example (the 1st example in http://zetcode.com/articles/javascriptjsonurl/), but it's not working. Did I miss anything? Appreciate your help!

My code pen link is:  https://codepen.io/Hance/pen/eErYrM

```js
$.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com', function(data) {
    
    var text = `Date: ${data.date}<br>
                Time: ${data.time}<br>
                Unix time: ${data.milliseconds_since_epoch}`
                
    
    $(".mypanel").html(text);
});
```

```html
<div class="mypanel"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you imported jquery in your codepen?  Check the console for errors.

Comment: Did you run it on a server with HTTPS? You cannot fetch data from a HTTP server from HTTPS. Check the console for any errors.

Comment: It is a good idea to implement a fail check https://jsfiddle.net/5cakp4zy/18/ you cannot make the request you are making. You can see the error in the console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you have actually installed the library -- jQuery in this case.

Works when using jQuery.

```
$.getJSON('http://time.jsontest.com', function(data) {

    var text = `Date: ${data.date}<br>
                Time: ${data.time}<br>
                Unix time: ${data.milliseconds_since_epoch}`


    $(".mypanel").html(text);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/qajiwujexi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Codepen.io to test your script since Codepen.io uses HTTPS and on an HTTPS page you can't request a resource from an insecure url (HTTP).

You could try using JS Bin which can be loaded over HTTP.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. By this question, I learned the HTTPS / HTTP and codepen / jsfiddle. Another baby steps forward. Harray~